# What is a state tracker?

Tags: opengl

What is a state tracker? I see this term a lot relating to the development of components for Gallium3D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The state tracker is the piece which interfaces core Mesa to the Gallium3D interface.
>
> It's responsible for translating Mesa state (blend modes, texture state, etc) and drawing commands (like glDrawArrays and glDrawPixels) into pipe objects and operations.

Source: http://dri.freedesktop.org/doxygen/gallium/statetracker.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the term 'state tracker' isn't a general development concept; it's specific to Mesa and Gallium3D.